# Discover and connect to the devices running the same app around globally without a server

Tags: mobile, blockchain, protocols, p2p, device-discovery

I want to create a mobile app which can connect to devices having the same app installed without having a server in between. The devices should act as server and client and discover nodes similar to them, like how it happens in block chain?

I firstly want to know the discovery protocol that how these devices will discover each other. I have seen the samples of sockets, TCP connection but they know the IP address before, in my case we do not know the IP address, have to discover similar nodes also with security like cryptography happens in block chain so, random device don't mess up with my chain.

Comment: This may help to start the journey https://blog.harmony.one/peer-discovery-in-harmony-network/ and https://developer.bitcoin.org/devguide/p2p_network.html

Comment: Great information thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am starting to learn about it, and one of the first things that came to my mind is [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call),  because is how Bitcoin works: [link](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/), and you can check also de P2P section in the link.

I will follow this and update my answer with the things I'll find.

Good luck.

Comment: sure thank you, also the initial nodes are hardcoded in the bitcoin core . but i dont want to hardcode , want to create some kind of discovery protocol which would map to the device by ip and mac address maybe , something like this

Comment: how does rpc technically works ?

Comment: any update to your project